# Use Apache Flink to only produce messages to a Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

From the examples I have seen the below code snippet and it works fine. But the problem is that : I don't always have requirements of processing the **input-stream** and produce it to a **sink**.

What if I have an application where based on some events I have to only publish to a kafka topic so that down-stream applications can make certain decisions. That means, I don't really have an **input-stream** but I just know when **something** happens in my application, I need to publish a message to a particular topic of kafka. That is, I only need a **sink**.

I was going through examples but didn't find anything matching to my requirements. Is there a way to only configure a **KafkaSink** that exposes a method() to be called for publishing messages to a topic.

Many thanks in advance!!

```
String inputTopic = "flink_input";
    String outputTopic = "flink_output";
    String consumerGroup = "baeldung";
    String address = "localhost:9092";
    StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment
      .getExecutionEnvironment();
    FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> flinkKafkaConsumer = createStringConsumerForTopic(
      inputTopic, address, consumerGroup);
    DataStream<String> stringInputStream = environment
      .addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);

    FlinkKafkaProducer011<String> flinkKafkaProducer = createStringProducer(
      outputTopic, address);

    stringInputStream
      .map(new WordsCapitalizer())
      .addSink(flinkKafkaProducer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a source. You might want to implement a custom source, or you could use something like a `NumberSequenceSource` followed by an operator like a process function that emits whatever you know you want to write to the sink, followed by the sink.

That process function could, for example, transform the incoming events into whatever you want to write to Kafka, or it could ignore its inputs and use a timer to generate the events to be sent to Kafka.

Or you might find that [async i/o](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/) is a better building block than a process function, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Let me try this. Will let you know if it works!

Comment: I used ```CustomSource extends RichSourceFunction<String> {}``` as you suggested it works seamlessly. The catch point was to make CustomSource a proper singleton by using ```protected Object readResolve() {}```. If its not coded as singleton, it wasn't working properly.